# Advantages of using filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE vs preg_match()

Tags: php, validation, filter, filtering, w3c

To validate input date, both form URL or from a form, which technique do you usually use?

I have been looking at [PHP Filters](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp) but i have rarely see them on any code.

I have usually seen the use of preg_mach, for example:

```
$numbers = "/^[0-9]+$/D";

if (preg_match($numbers, $var)){
    echo "is number";
}
```

Instead of:

```
if(!filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
    echo "is number";
}
```

Is there any advantage using one or another?

Comment: use the filter, they are relatively new (PHP 5.2.0) which is why you haven't seen them much

Comment: @Dragon - `2006-11-02` is relatively new?

Comment: **relatively** yes. the universe is between 12 and 14 billion years old, so 6 years old is NEW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Php introduced the filer_ functionality for a wide range of types of variable validation since php 5.2. It's good practice to use the [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) || [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for your needs.

Besides the fact that it's safer it will also save you lots of development time cracking your head over regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

My two cents: **It depends.**

It depends on the situation on whether you should use the filter functions over a regex. Actually, the criteria is pretty simple:

Is there a `filter_*` function that exists that validates *exactly* the kind of input I'm expecting?

- If so, use that `filter_*` function.
- Otherwise, use a regex.

Regexs are more complex than the `filter_*` functions, but the functionality of `filter_*` and regexs are very loosely correlated. Most likely, a regex can be crafted to do the job of a `filter_*` function, but it doesn't work the other way around. So, regexes bring increased functionality and flexibility to the table while also being more complex.

Personally, when dealing with simple inputs (integers, dates, times), I use a `filter_*` function, while more complex inputs or very specific or custom inputs (custom identifier that should start and end with a letter and have 3 digits in between) are more suited for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use filter. It is made specifically for validation. A regular expression is always custom and if you write it yourself, you can forget many things which need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Both are doing the same thing but filters would seem to be the simpler and nicer option to use, you could also use value ranges if you wanted.

If you wanted to do something other that just check for a valid number and a bit more complex involving strings also then using a regular expression might be the way to go however.